Access Mail through a particular Server
I am not sure if this is a correct platform to ask but as I find this question almost similar to my problem, that's why I am posting it here.
I have a mail account set at myname@mail.institute. But the server mail.institute is not accessible from outside the institute's network, except for a dedicated frontend website they plugged in.
The problem is I cannot sync that mail account in my Mail client apps like Thunderbird, Gmail, outlook etc. unless I am inside the Institute.
The specifications that works for mail clients (Gmail App) inside campus:
Incoming Setting: server: mail.institute, port: 143, security: None.
Outgoing Setting: SMTP server: mail.institute, port: 587, security: STARTTLS.
Luckily, they provide a machine say A, which is accessible from outside (thus we can access any machine inside institute using ssh after ssh-ing this machine A) .
Can I setup some settings in some existing mail clients (say Thunderbird, but Android settings is more preferable) which will  transitively use machine A to sync my mails from outside the campus?

there are 8 possible solutions to your issue in the linked question. If none of them work, please [edit] your question and explain why they are different.

talk to the institute's IT support

@graham I can see this related question somewhat similar other than the one I linked. But it's full of technical jargons. I think the question is self-explanatory. If not please mention where do I need to explain more.

If you can ssh to the machine A, then you should be able to setup ssh tunnels to the server mail.institute over that machine (unless they blocked connections from machine A to mail.institute). Use for example the following command:
ssh -L 6000:mail.institute:143 -L 6001:mail.institute:587 machineA

and then set up your mail client to use localhost port 6000 for incoming mail and localhost port 6001 for outgoing mail.
You can change 6000 and 6001 above to whichever ports you want, as long as no application uses them on your local machine.
Of course this will work only during ssh session being active.

Well, this works fine with Thunderbird. But what are the equivalent options in Android that correspond to localhost and ssh tunneling.

localhost is localhost, that doesn't change. As for ssh tunneling, you must research the available ssh clients for Android and check if they support tunneling. "Local port forwarding" is the setting you should look for.
I guess ssh command under Termux should support this - although I didn't check (If you don't know, Termux is an application that provides a nice Linux command line environment on your Android device. It is recommended to use version of Termux available on F-Droid as the version from Google Play store has some known issues).

Tested in Termux with ssh inside mail client Apps Outlook and Edison Email. Working Fine, except for the fact that while sending mails SMTP security is making a noise. Could not send mail from Outlook. But Edison Mail did the job with security set to Auto.

Follow Up Question: Can tmux under Termux do the job of keeping the ssh alive even when Termux is off? I was trying from inside a tmux session under Termux. In that case the account setup was not connecting.

I don't know. Try asking this on Android site ( https://android.stackexchange.com/ ), maybe someone can answer.
